# DELETE DATA React express.js

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express

Routes : users.js file :

```
const express = require("express");
const { getUser, deleteForm } = require("../controller/user.js");

const router = express.Router();

router.get("/find/:username", getUser);
router.delete("/:formId", deleteForm)

module.exports = router;
```

controller : user.js file :

```
const { db } = require("../connect.js");


exports.getUser = function(req, res) {
  const username = req.params.username;
  const q = "SELECT * FROM  users WHERE username=?";

  db.query(q, [username], function(err, data) {
    if (err) return res.status(500).json(err);
    const { password, ...info } = data[0];
    return res.json(info);
    
  });
  console.log(username)
};


exports.deleteForm = function(req, res) {
  const formId = req.params.formId
  const q = "DELETE FROM form WHERE id = ?";
  db.query(q, [formId], function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).json(err);

    }
    if (result.affectedRows === 0) {
      return res.status(404).json({message:"Form not found"})
    }
    return res.json({message: "Form deleted successfully"})
  })

}
```

Admin.jsx file :

```
import React from 'react';
import Dashboard from '../../Components/Dashboard/Dashboard';
import Logout from '../../Components/Logout/Logout';



const Admin = ({formId}) => {
  function deleteForm(e, formId) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(formId)
    fetch(`http://localhost:5000/backend/users/${formId}`, {
        method: "DELETE"
    })
    .then((result) => result.json())
    .then((resp) => {
      console.warn(resp);
      if (resp.message === "Form deleted successfully") 
        
        localStorage.clear();
       
      
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
}
  
  return (
    <div>
      <Logout/>
      <Dashboard/>
      <button onClick={(e) => deleteForm(e, formId)} className="delete-button">
        Delete FORM
      </button>
      
    </div>
  )
}

export default Admin;
```

Im trying to make the admin delete the form instead of getting the form deleted i got this error from the browser : http://localhost:5000/backend/users/undefined 404 (Not Found)
{message: 'Form not found'}

can anyone help me to make this function work .....and im passing the formid value as prop is it correct or no

Comment: Then `formId` is `undefined`.  Which means `form.id` is `undefined`.  What value do you expect it to have and why?  Where in the code shown do you provide that value?

Comment: exports.deleteForm = function(req, res) {
  const formId = req.params.formId
  const q = "DELETE FROM form WHERE id = ?";
  db.query(q, [formId], function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).json(err);

    }
    if (result.affectedRows === 0) {
      return res.status(404).json({message:"Form not found"})
    }
    return res.json({message: "Form deleted successfully"})
  })

} from the backend function

Comment: No, that's now where you supply the value to produce the URL.  The problem is happening when constructing the URL to make the request to the back-end.  So clearly the problem happens on the *front-end*.  Where do you use this `DeleteForm` component in React, and what `id` value do you pass to its props?

Comment: admin component : import React from 'react';
import Dashboard from '../../Components/Dashboard/Dashboard';
import Logout from '../../Components/Logout/Logout';
import { DeleteForm } from '../../Components/DeleteForm';


const Admin = () => {

  
  return (
    <div>
      <Logout/>
      <Dashboard/>
      <DeleteForm/>
      
    </div>
  )
}

export default Admin; .......( and what id value do you pass to its props?) for that im passing form as a props from the DeleteForm component ........to be more clear my problem is with the url and id value ?

Comment: Relevant code belongs in the question, not in comments where it is barely readable.  And according to that code you are not passing any `id` prop to `<DeleteForm/>`, which is why the `id` prop value in `DeleteForm` is `undefined`.

Comment: i've updated my code and i don't know if im passing the id value as prop is correct or not

Comment: Well, the updated code is no longer using a `<DeleteForm>` component.  So if you're asking whether or not you are correctly passing props to your `<DeleteForm>` component then I guess the answer would be "No", because you can't pass props to a component that you're not using in the first place.  If your intent with the updated code was to refactor/rewrite the functionality entirely then you are encouraged to test and debug your new code.  When you do that, do you observe a specific problem?  What problem do you observe and what debugging information have you observed?

Comment: i tried to log the formId before the fetch and it's undefined

Comment: What value do you expect `formId` to have and why?  The `Admin` component is passing `formId` to the function `deleteForm`, and the `Admin` component gets that value from its props.  But nowhere in the code shown are you actually *using* `<Admin>` as a component or passing any props to it.  Where do you use this component and what value are you passing for its `formId` prop?  So far you're just going in circles without ever tracing back to where this value *comes from* and what you expect it to be or why.

Comment: .app.js file :  <Route
              path="/admin"
              element={<ProtectedRoute element={Admin} />} 
            />.........first the admin page im using it to display the dashboard where the admin has a data grid with the form id... name and other data ............i fethed those data in the dashboard component and it works well  and i think the delete function is a good option for my client so he can delete the form if he want ....the best option to delete the form is by Id i believe .....so if you can show me how to pass a value to formId

Comment: Continuing the same circle... Relevant code belongs in the question, not in comments where it is barely readable. As for the code in that comment, nowhere do you pass a prop to `Admin`.  Perhaps you meant to do something like this?: `<Route path="/admin" element={<ProtectedRoute element={<Admin formId={someValue} />} />`  I don't know what value you're looking to use for the `formId`, all I know is that nowhere in your code are you using any value for it. Whatever value you *want* to use, wherever that value comes from, that's where you would get it. But the code shown has no such information.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are passing the `formId` as props to the `Admin` component. Check your parent component where you are using the `Admin` component.

It needs to look like:

```
<Admin formId={20} />
```

And request URL needs to look like `http://localhost:5000/backend/users/20`

Comment: Thank you .. I've fixed that by taking the value from the row in dashboard and it works fine for the delete and the update status